# pug for loop - trying to dynamically create # of li items via a number passed in by mixin argument

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to dynamically create a number of `li`s equals to the number passed in by a mixin. I tried using for loops, but nothing is being generated.

Here is what the mixin looks like:

```
mixin grid-content(liCount,itemTitle1, itemDescriptionTitle1, itemDescription1, itemTitle2, itemDescriptionTitle2, itemDescription2, itemTitle3, itemDescriptionTitle3, itemDescription3)
    - var count = liCount
    .grid-content
        .container
            .row
                ul.grid-content__list.grid-content__list--not-news
                    each val in count
                        li.grid-content__item
                            h1.item-title=itemTitle+count
                            .item-content
                                h3.item-description-title=itemDescriptionTitle+count
                                p.item-description=itemDescription+count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things going on here. First, consider the following:

Say `count = 3`. One might think `p= itemTitle+count` is equivalent to `p= itemTitle3`, but it's not. Instead, it looks for a variable called `itemTitle` and tries to sum its value with a variable called `count`, which doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to create a mixin that can easily accept any number of grid items, consider passing an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

You might consider an approach like this:

```
// My Grid items

-
  var myGridItems = [
    {
      title: 'Item One Title',
      description: {
        title: 'Item One Description Title',
        contents: 'Item One Description Contents'
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Item Two Title',
      description: {
        title: 'Item Two Description Title',
        contents: 'Item Two Description Contents'
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Item Three Title',
      description: {
        title: 'Item Three Description Title',
        contents: 'Item Three Description Contents'
      }
    }
  ]


// My Mixin

mixin gridContent(items)

  .grid-content
    .container
      .row
        ul.grid-content__list.grid-content__list--not-news

          each item in items

            li.grid-content__item
              h1.item-title= item.title
              .item-content
                h3.item-description-title= item.description.title
                 p.item-description= item.description.contents


// Calling the Mixin

+gridContent(myGridItems)
```

Comment: okay okay, makes sense. How can I dynamically pass in the title or other contents for each different li item?

Comment: That's what this is doing